# Не загружаются изображения на api 20 и ниже

Tags: android, android-layout

Выбивает ошибку при тесте на устройствах api 20 и ниже.

Вот такая ошибка,когда убрал картинку drawable/man:

```
E/UncaughtException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200c5
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2354)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:425)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:129)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:211)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:186)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:197)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:508)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1160)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:234)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:292)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1047)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1074)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:460)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Код layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Profile.Profile"
    android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@id/tvPhoto"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="119dp"
            android:src="@drawable/man"
            app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_name"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:gravity="end" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/e"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_email"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:gravity="end" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_phone"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:gravity="end" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Код:

```
package by.ittech.test_chat.Profile;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import by.ittech.test_chat.EditProfile;
import by.ittech.test_chat.R;

import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext;


public class Profile extends Fragment {

    DatabaseReference myRef;
    private TextView profileName;
    private TextView profileEmail;
    private TextView profilePhone;
    private ImageView photo;
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 500;
    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
    public Profile() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        profileName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        profileEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        profilePhone = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_phone);
        photo=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoto);
        setData();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView-Profile");
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_edit:
                Fragment fragment=new EditProfile();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                Log.i(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected");
            default:
                // Not one of ours. Perform default menu processing
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }


    public void setData(){

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        profileEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles").child(user.getUid());
        StorageReference myRefImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()+"/img.jpg");
        myRefImage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                if(uri==null){
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon).fit().centerCrop().into(photo);
                }else{
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(photo);
                }
            }
        });
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ProfileUserInfo userInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfileUserInfo.class);
                if (userInfo == null) {
                    profileName.setText("");
                    profilePhone.setText("");
                } else {
                    profileName.setText(userInfo.getName());
                    profilePhone.setText(userInfo.getPhone());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        Log.i(TAG, "setData");
    }

}
```

Как я понимаю,ругается на данную библиотеку: com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView, но почему,если на других устройствах всё работает. До этого была такая же ошибка с другой библиотекой,которая скругляет углы.

Протестировал сейчас со стандартным ImageView,выбивает такую же ошибку и ссылается на данную строку:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
```

Comment: А что Вы ожидали? Ясен пень ресурс не найден раз его там нет. Атрибут android:src из layout файла вообще уберите и посмотрите сможет ли потом программно вставить скачанную из сети. А саму картинку верните - она у Вас ещё и в меню прописана.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66058/discussion-on-question-by-shcherbuk-----api-20--).